# Java: extract group number from Matcher

Tags: java, regex

Very short question, it is possible to extract groups numbers, found by the Matcher?

for example here is my code:

```
Pattern k = Pattern.compile("(рис.\\s(\\d+)|[Рр]исунок\\s(\\d+)|[Рр]исунку\\s(\\d+)|fig.\\s(\\d+)|[fF]igure\\s(\\d+))");
Matcher m = k.matcher(DOMNode.getTextContent());

            while(m.find()) {           
              domElement.setAttribute("rid", "fig" + m.group(!1));
            }
```

With this pattern I can get several full matches. They would be grouped as match 1: group 1, group 2; match 2: group 1, group 3; match 3: group 1, group 4

I want to append to DOM element attribute from the second group. In the cycle it will be group 2 from first match, group 3 from second match etc.

Comment: you can name your groups with the syntax `"(?<groupId>.*)"` into your pattern and then call `matcher.group("groupId")`. It's more readable and should enable you to do what you want.

Comment: Will keep it in mind. Didn't know about this feature.

Comment: You don't need to do it like this. You're not really enforcing an order via the number of the match. You can just use this `([Pр]исунок|[Pр]исунку|рис.|[Ff]igure|fig.)\s(\d+)`  If you are trying to enforce an order, you only need 1 match to get them all `(?:рис.\s(\d+)).*?(?:[Рр]исунок\s(\d+)).*?(?:[Рр]исунку\s(\d+)).*?(?:fig.\s(\d+)).*?(?:[fF]igure\s(\d+))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all groups starting from 2nd group and find the first non-null group and populate your dom:

```
while(m.find()) {
   for (c=2; c<=m.groupCount(); c++) {
       if (m.group(c) != null) {
           domElement.setAttribute("rid", "fig" + m.group(c));
           break;
       }
   }
}
```